# FORMSOF Thesaurus in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, full-text-search, thesaurus

Has anyone done any performance measures with this in terms of speed where there is a high number of substitutes for any given word. For instance, I want to use this to store common misspellings; expecting to have 4-10 variations of a word.

```
<expansion>
   <sub>administration</sub>
   <sub>administraton</sub>
   <sub>aministraton</sub>
</expansion>
```

When you run a fulltext search, how does performance degrade with that number of variations? for instance, I assume it has to do a separate fulltext search performing an OR?

Also, having say 20/30K entries in the Thesaurus xml file - does this impact performance?

Comment: Did you ever get anywhere with this?

Answer (score 0):

No, but performance testing is very often quite system-specific. I'd suggest putting together some sample data and running your own test cases is your best bet.