# SQL - searching database with the LIKE operator

Tags: sql, sql-like, spelling

Given your data stored somewhere in a database:

```
Hello my name is Tom I like dinosaurs to talk about SQL.  
SQL is amazing. I really like SQL.
```

We want to implement a site search, allowing visitors to enter terms and return relating records.  A user might search for:

```
Dinosaurs
```

And the SQL:

```
WHERE articleBody LIKE '%Dinosaurs%'
```

Copes fine with returning the correct set of records.

How would we cope however, if a user mispells dinosaurs?  IE:

```
Dinosores
```

(Poor sore dino).  How can we search allowing for error in spelling?  We can associate common misspellings we see in search with the correct spelling, and then search on the original terms + corrected term, but this is time consuming to maintain.

Any way programatically?

**Edit**

Appears SOUNDEX could help, but can anyone give me an example using soundex where entering the search term:

```
Dinosores wrocks
```

returns records instead of doing:

```
WHERE articleBody LIKE '%Dinosaurs%' OR articleBody LIKE '%Wrocks%'
```

which would return squadoosh?

Comment: levenshtein distance or Soundex

Comment: Depending on the DB you're using... there are "Soundex" functions that can be used to get a "match" on words that sound alike...

Comment: I don't think this can be done purely in SQL. Wildcard searches are already slow. I'd rather use a finished product like Apache Lucene or Solr.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're using SQL Server, have a look at [SOUNDEX](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187384.aspx).

For your example:

```
select SOUNDEX('Dinosaurs'), SOUNDEX('Dinosores')
```

Returns identical values (D526) .

You can also use DIFFERENCE function (on same link as soundex) that will compare levels of similarity (4 being the most similar, 0 being the least).

```
SELECT DIFFERENCE('Dinosaurs', 'Dinosores'); --returns 4
```

**Edit:**

After hunting around a bit for a multi-text option, it seems that this isn't all that easy. I would refer you to the link on the Fuzzt Logic answer provided by @Neil Knight (+1 to that, for me!).

[This stackoverflow article](https://stackoverflow.com/q/921978/144491) also details possible sources for implentations for Fuzzy Logic in TSQL. Once respondant also outlined Full text Indexing as a potential that you might want to investigate.

Comment: How would you apply this to a multi keyword search?

Comment: Like say I enter in my search 'dinosores wrock' (meaning dinosaurs rock).  Traditionally I would do: WHERE body LIKE '%dinosores%' OR body LIKE 'wrock'.  How can I apply soundex in this case so it returns records?

Comment: @James, how about when articleBody is stored, is stores the SOUNDEX version of it, IE "blah blah lol" and "B32 B32 L122".  When you search for terms, you search for LIKE's on the soundex.  Would this work well?

Comment: I consider this solved! I'm going to make a new question though because this is fascinating.

Comment: @James: Surely you can +1 Me ;-)

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps your RDBMS has a `SOUNDEX` function?  You didn't mention which one was involved here.

- [SQL Server's `SOUNDEX`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187384.aspx)

Comment: Yes it will, SOUNDEX looks amazing, never heard of it before!

Answer (score 3):

Just to throw an alternative out there.  If SSIS is an option, then you can use Fuzzy Lookup.

[SSIS Fuzzy Lookup](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345128%28SQL.90%29.aspx)

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure if introducing a separate "search engine" is possible, but if you look at products like the Google search appliance or Autonomy, these products can index a SQL database and provide more searching options - for example, handling misspellings as well as synonyms, search results weighting, alternative search recommendations, etc.

Also, SQL Server's full-text search feature can be configured to use a thesaurus, which might help:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms142491.aspx

Here is another SO question from someone setting up a thesaurus to handle common misspellings:
[FORMSOF Thesaurus in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2160884/formsof-thesaurus-in-sql-server)

Answer (score 1):

Short answer, there is nothing built in to most SQL engines that can do dictionary-based correction of "fat fingers". SoundEx does work as a tool to find words that would sound alike and thus correct for phonetic misspellings, but if the user typed in "Dinosars" missing the final U, or truly "fat-fingered" it and entered "Dinosayrs", SoundEx would not return an exact match.

Sounds like you want something on the level of Google Search's "Did you mean ***_*_**?" feature. I can tell you that is not as simple as it looks. At a 10,000-foot level, the search engine would look at each of those keywords and see if it's in a "dictionary" of known "good" search terms. If it isn't, it uses an algorithm much like a spell-checker suggestion to find the dictionary word that is the closest match (requires the fewest letter substitutions, additions, deletions and transpositions to turn the given word into the dictionary word). This will require some heavy procedural code, either in a stored proc or CLR Db function in your database, or in your business logic layer.

Comment: I didn't want to simulate the sophistication of Google, but just have a site search that could cope with spellings as a lot of visitors are coming from all over the world, but thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 0):

You can also try the `SubString()`, to eliminate the first 3 or so characters . Below is an example of how that can be achieved

```
SELECT Fname, Lname  
FROM Table1 ,Table2
WHERE substr(Table1.Fname, 1,3) || substr(Table1.Lname,1 ,3) = substr(Table2.Fname, 1,3) || substr(Table2.Lname, 1 , 3))
ORDER BY Table1.Fname;
```